# How to increase availability for Azure storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

For Azure storage accounts the SLA for write requests is 99.9% regardless if I'm using LRS, ZRS, GRS or RA-GRS. Is there a way to increase the SLA for write requests on the storage account?

E.g is there a good way to fail over to another storage account in another region?

The accounts don't have to contain the same data. I just want to always be able to store the blobs.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a good way to fail over to another storage account in another region?

Of course, Azure storage itself provides this feature, you can refer to the document [Initiate a storage account failover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-initiate-account-failover?tabs=azure-portal#initiate-the-failover).

Before you can perform an account failover on your storage account, make sure that your storage account is configured for `geo-replication`. Your storage account can use any of the following redundancy options:

1. Geo-redundant storage (GRS) or read-access geo-redundant storage (RA-GRS)
2. Geo-zone-redundant storage (GZRS) or read-access geo-zone-redundant storage (RA-GZRS)

You will see an interface like this:

[image]

> Is there a way to increase the SLA for write requests on the storage account?

My suggestion is to increase the number of retries for write requests, maybe the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/retry-service-specific#blobs-queues-and-files) here can help you, you can use [BlobClientOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclientoptions?view=azure-dotnet).

Comment: Ok but from what I can understand this failover you're describing takes about an hour and that's too long. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-disaster-recovery-guidance?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json

Comment: Hi,@HedenDenQvisten. You can create multiple storage accounts and create a blob trigger function. When a file is written, this function will be triggered and written to the second storage account. Note that this is another storage account, not `secondary regions `.

Comment: There are two benefits to doing so: 1. During the failover, the data in the `primary region` is lost, you can [Check the Last Sync Time property for a storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/last-sync-time-get?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=azure-powershell) and then copy the lost data from the second storage account to the first storage account after the failover is completed.

Comment: 2. When a failure occurs, the write request fails, and the data can be written to the second storage area. After the failover, the data can be written to the first storage account.

Comment: you say that if I write request fails the data can be written to the second storage and then when the first account is up and running the data can be written to the first account. This is exactly what I want but how does that process work? I have an azure function which writes to the storage account and that can't know when to switch back from the second to the first